# fail2ban running on CentOS 7 & getting “ssh connection refused”

Tags: fail2ban, centos7

Is anyone successfully running `fail2ban` on CentOS 7 and can tell me how to do it?

I tried to install `fail2ban` with `yum install fail2ban` and run it (there are no extra rules in `iptables -L` which seems odd according to what I found on the net).

As soon as I reboot the server I can't login as root or other user via ssh. The ports are not visible when scanning and of course I get this error when I try to connect:

```
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 12321: Connection refused
```

I changed the ssh port, but I also tried it with port 22 without luck.

I wonder if someone knows a solutions to this problem?

It has to be a problem with `fail2ban` because I didn't install anything else.

---

UPDATE
I can log in via ssh after reboot. But no html page is served. Output of `iptables -L`:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination          f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   multiport dports ssh ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
>   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination          ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
>   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination          OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere
>
> Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere            [goto]  FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere            [goto]
>
> Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references) target     prot opt
>   source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere            [goto]  FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere            [goto]
>
> Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references) target     prot opt
>   source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDI_public (2 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere
>
> Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDO_public (2 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere
>
> Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   [goto]  IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   [goto]
>
> Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain INPUT_direct (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain IN_public (2 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere
>
> Chain IN_public_allow (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
>
> Chain IN_public_deny (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain IN_public_log (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain f2b-sshd (1 references) target     prot opt source
>   destination          RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Comment: What else did you do besides install fail2ban? Doing that doesn't disable all connectivity.

Comment: This has nothing to do with fail2ban. Get on the console and look carefully at your firewall.

Comment: Connection refused generally means nothing is listening on the relevant IP:post. Your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the responses so far. I did nothing beside installing fail2ban and reboot. No problem to use ssh or connect to the server after a reboot unless I install fail2ban.

Comment: ok, got it to work with "sudo yum install fail2ban ipset" (to be honest I don't know about the difference with or without ipset) and I can ssh again after reboot, but the server (nginx) doesn't serve a html page on the ip address after reboot. I guess something has changed my firewall. Can someone please have a look at the attached output of iptables -L

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25577828 solved my problems

Answer (score 3):

I installed ~20 CentOS 7 servers with `fail2ban` out of the box and the default configuration is very open so a "connection refused" comes only after 5 failed login tries.

CentOS 7 now uses `firewalld`, but a rule for ssh(22) is set up per default.
If you change the ssh port in `sshd_config`, you also have to adjust the firewalld-rule, i.e.:

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=12321/tcp --permanent
```

Remember to run `firewall-cmd --reload` after changing configuration.

Better you just test with a fresh reinstall of CentOS, install `fail2ban`, restart and I can’t see any reason why you shouldn't be able to login if it worked before (make sure that eth0 is up and has an IP address! I tend to forget "autoconnect" at installation time)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I did exactly like you suggested. Fresh install of Centos 7 and fail2ban and reboot -> not possible to log in ... while rebooting before installing fail2ban is no problem at all :-(

Comment: And you leave default port 22? Is fail2ban enabled on boot? What if you do "service fail2ban stop" and try again?

Answer (score 0):

ISP's like amazon have their own firewall.  if your ISP has this service you have to open up your IP in there in order to get through.